# Displaying a computed field with multiple lines? (xpages)

Tags: xpages, computed-field

OK, I have a customer name and address and simply want to display this in one computed field instead of separate lines in a table to save real estate.  I've tried several iterations of @newline but to no avail.  Can someone give me some guidance?

I would also like to NOT include Address2 if it's blank.  I'm new to javascript.  Thanks for your help.

```
var a = document1.getItemValueString("CompanyName");
var b = document1.getItemValueString("Address1");
var c = document1.getItemValueString("Address2");
var d = @Char(13);
a + @NewLine() + b + "<br>" + c;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set property `escape="false"` in computed field and add `<br />` whenever you want a newline.

You can set this property in properties tab selecting content type "HTML" too:

[image]

Your code would be

```
var a = document1.getItemValueString("CompanyName");
var b = document1.getItemValueString("Address1");
var c = document1.getItemValueString("Address2");
a + "<br />" + b + (c ? "<br />" + c : "");
```

Comment: Could do the same without HTML and add in newline characters `\n` instead of HTML break tags.

Comment: @Eric: unfortunately, `\n` doesn't work. Text rows are divided by newline inside a span when sent to browser but browser changes newlines to spaces.

Comment: Completely right re: the `span` tag. I know I've done this before, but whatever I must have done at the time would probably be more intensive that switching to HTML content.

Comment: Be aware that using escape=false with user-submitted data can give Cross Site Scripting (XSS) security vulnerabilities.
e.g malicious user A sets their address to:
`<script> alert('executing script'); // script to submit user's session authentication to user A's server </script>`
And then innocent user B looks at user A's address, user B's info is sent to user A's server, and user A can pretend to be user B.
Using escape=true ensures that `<script>` in an address will not be treated as active browser JavaScript 
and will instead be present in the HTML as `&lt;script&gt;`.

Answer (score 4):

Mike,

I had to do nearly the same thing recently and used a Multiline Edit Box. Place your same code in data section of an `<xp:inputTextArea>` (Multiline Edit Box in palette) and then make it read-only.

[image]